# Does electric field rotates with moving electron, due to spin? Does spin influence on electric field at all?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electric-fields

When electron moves, its electric field contracts, and becomes asymmetric. If spin means that electron rotates around itself, does the electric field rotates too?

Does spin influence on electric field at all?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Keep in mind that the electron spin is a purely quantum notion and has nothing to do with the classical momentum of an object rotating by its axis. Thus, you should not think of an electron rotating around itself since it is a quantum particle and not a classical object (like a ball or a top, for example).

Comment: @GK, I edited question a little bit

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question exactly, but we are usually dealing with electrons propagating inside a fixed electric field. Thus, if you are familiar with the concept of a Hamiltonian, you will get an extra interaction term which is due to the interaction of the spin of the electron and the underlying electric field. This is the well-known "spin-orbit interaction" and you can read some things about it at the Wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93orbit_interaction.

Comment: @GK, okay, electric field contracts in constant motion direction. Does contracted electric field is what do we call magnetic field?

Comment: @GK, didn't find answer there. It's too basic